# Matlab double integration result does not match with my self calculate

Tags: integration, self-learning, matlab

Here is a double integration, self learning
$$ P=\int_{-w}^{w}\int_{l}^{\frac{y_h(x_b+w)}{x_h}+l}\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}\left[\frac{\log{\frac{z_h(y_b-l)}{y_h}}-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right]\space dy_bdx_b$$

after derive the final formula. I used matlab to verify my result by codes

```
fun = @(x,y) (0.5*erfc((log(zh*(y-l)/yh)-mu)/(sqrt(2)*sigma)));
ymax = @(x) (yh/xh*(x+w))+l;
q = integral2(fun,-w,w,l,ymax);
```

but the result is not compatible with my own integration result. and I think is there something wrong with the MATLAB CODES?

Comment: You can let brackets (and other paired delimiters) adjust to the size of their content using `\left` and `\right`. Also, you can get the right font for functions like $\operatorname{erfc}$ that don't have a special command of their own using `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: Are you sure we won't be able to help you better if you include the two different results?

Comment: I highly doubt there is something wrong with matlab. It is possible that the numerical sensitivity of `erfc` induces error near zero; however, without a comparison of your computations to your numerical results, it is impossible to answer this.